# Creating a flag based on last digit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a column with a number with 1 decimal. e.g. 1234.8

Number of digits varies.

How do I extract the last round digit (4) and create a flag where rows ending in 4 or 5 = 1 and the rest = 0.

```
Col          Flag
1234.8       1
3345.5       1
23.1         0
567902.3     0
```

I'm on python 2.7

Comment: You need to clarify your question. expected input/output and exactly what you are looking for it to do

Comment: `num = 1234.8; d = int(num) % 10; # do whatever now`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a string and check the last character.

```
def ends_in_45(num):
    if str(int(num))[-1] in "45":
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last digit by converting to an integer first (strips the fraction), then dividing modulo 10.

```
last_digit = int(x) % 10
```